# How did I make this soccer-ball/honeycomb shape?

Tags: modeling

A while ago, I made this:

[image: object]

Now, I'd like to make something like it again, but I can't remember how I did it the first time.

I'm pretty sure I started with an icosphere, then maybe I used a modifier. I'm not sure how I "carved out" the spaces between each hexagon. The larger open areas I deleted manually, though.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Bevel modifier

- Start by adding an **Icosphere** with `3` levels of subdivision
- Add a **Bevel** modifier with **Vertex Only** option enabled. Now you should
  have the main pattern clearly visible.

[image]

As we want to delete the inner exagon of each loop, we can take advance of the modifier to add a distinctive feature to those faces in order to select them easily: increase the number of **Segments** to `2`.

Then, in order to make the shapes less regular, decrease the **Width** value to something like `0.09`.

- Add a second **Bevel** of wanted Width modifier to create a "corridor" between the "main" faces.

[image]

- Apply both modifiers, enter edit mode, pick one exagonal n-gon and select similar area faces with a threshold of `0.006`, invert selection and delete other faces.

[image]

- Final touch with **Solidify** modifier.

Result:

[image]

Comment: Nice answer!  But in the original, the hexagons have three long edges and three short edges.  Any idea how that happened?

Comment: Thanks @John-PaulGignac for pointing it out, I didn't notice it at first. It depends on the Width value you use in the first Bevel. I've edited the answer in this sense, providing values for the shown example.