# How would I go about creating holes in mesh

Tags: modeling

I want to model this old microphone and wanted to know if anyone had any ideas on how to specifically model the inset holes of the microphone?

[image]

Comment: There are plenty of questions like this already. [A](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66769/how-to-transform-a-plane-into-a-honeycomb/80753#80753) [B](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52453/how-can-i-build-a-model-out-of-hexagons-honeycomb-effect) [C](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87384/add-repeating-pattern-to-surface) [D](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/105508/making-holes-in-an-object-using-an-image-as-a-reference) which mostly advise using the tissue addon

Comment: Then there is the "there is no spoon" workflow: maybe just use a texture to make the holes transparent.

Comment: And [E](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40997/how-can-i-make-a-hexagonal-grill)  [F](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98957/bend-a-honeycomb-mesh) [G](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50665/how-to-generate-a-metal-mesh/50672#50672) which advise other ways