# How do i create a perfect hexagonal dome like the image below?

Tags: modeling

[image: hexagonal dome shape]

How would I create the model of

> [The Pacific Theatre's Cinerama
>   Dome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinerama_Dome)
>
> The Cinerama Dome is the only concrete geodesic dome in the world. The
>   theatre is made up of 316 individual hexagonal and pentagonal shapes
>   in 16 different sizes.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The linked answer does not itself respond to the question in the link here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/52453/how-can-i-build-a-model-out-of-hexagons-honeycomb-effect. So how can this one be a duplicate? If a perfect tesselation is not possible, this real dome exists. So may be a way to approximate it.

Comment: It is likely that the hexagons are not regularly sized, they may get smaller towards the top. There may well be a pentagon at the top as well. If we had the building name, it might be possible to look up details on the tesselation which would help.

Comment: Thank you for the response, the building is called the Pacific Cinerama Dome.

Comment: Reece, Does the duplicate answer answer your question?, or is it different as suggested, and if so how?

Comment: The IcoSphere primitive is basically the same thing, just select all the center points and scale them out from where the object was generated. That's it.

Comment: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/meshes/primitives.html#icosphere

Comment: The duplicate answers my question as it achieves a very similar result. Thank you all for your help!