# Making a dome with Hexagons and Pentagons

Tags: modeling, mesh

I want to create a Dome mesh with Hexagons and Pentagons.

- Each side of every Hexagon needs to be the same size
- Each side of every Pentagon needs to be the same size
- Use of Pentagons is optional

The shape of the Dome should have more hexagons and pentagons (a denser geometry) than a **football**

Is there a plugin or a python script for this?

I tried using the geodesic dome plugin, but it always ends up giving me hexagons with different lengths (even when I specify the frequency to be 1)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/148932/how-do-i-create-a-perfect-hexagonal-dome-like-the-image-below

Comment: @RobinBetts But I don't know if it is even possible mathematical at a higher resolution to keep the hexagons equilateral and create a sphere. The geodesic polyhedrons of higher frequencies in the Wikipedia article also seem to have different sized hexagons so I guess this is "normal". Just as a comparison (which looks like what I think is the desired result): [Conway polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_geodesic_polyhedra_and_Goldberg_polyhedra#/media/File:Conway_polyhedron_Dk6k5tI.png) Akila: do you have an example where this is actually the case, that they are all the same size?

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann hexes not regular in your ref? Instinctively I suspect it's _not_ possible, once you're not _directly_  a dual of a Platonic solid, inheriting  its symmetry?

Comment: @RobinBetts The red and blue ones are regular, the yellow ones are not...